# (Geo) Mesa agent based model not displaying results and no model stepping

Tags: python, agent-based-modeling, mesa

I am trying to create an agent based model for city fire based on wild fire example: https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/tree/master/examples/forest_fire/forest_fire

The code below is not displaying any results and the model is not stepping.
Option 2 (commented in the model) is running an infinite loop.

I am missing something pretty fundamental I believe ...

```
 import os
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import geopandas as gpd
    from shapely.geometry import box
    import random
    from mesa import Model, Agent
    from mesa.time import RandomActivation
    from mesa.space import Grid
    from mesa.datacollection import DataCollector
    from mesa.batchrunner import BatchRunner
    from mesa_geo import GeoSpace, GeoAgent, AgentCreator
    from mesa.visualization.modules import CanvasGrid
    from mesa.visualization.ModularVisualization import ModularServer


path = "G:/Sync/FFE/Mesa"

# crop data
minx, miny = 1748570, 5426959
maxx, maxy = 1748841, 5427115
bbox = box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)

gdf_buildings = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(path, "buildings_raw.shp"), bbox=bbox)
# gdf_buildings.plot()
gdf_buildings['IgnProb_bl'] = 0.1

# plot map of agents
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
gdf_buildings.plot(column='IgnProb_bl', ax=ax, legend=True)

# wind scenario
wind = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, 'GD_wind.csv'))


def wind_scenario(wind_data=wind):
    i = np.random.randint(0, wind_data.shape[0])
    w = wind_data.iloc[i, 2]
    d = wind_data.iloc[i, 1]
    return w, d


class Buildings(GeoAgent):
    """
    building footprint.
    Conditions: "Fine", "On Fire", "Burned Out"
    """

    def __init__(self, unique_id, model, shape):
        super().__init__(unique_id, model, shape)
        self.condition = "Fine"
        wind_direction, critical_distance = wind_scenario()
        self.direction = wind_direction
        self.distance = critical_distance

    def step(self):
        '''
        if building is on fire, spread it to buildings according to wind conditions
        '''
        # option 1
        # print("STEP AGENT")
        neighbors = self.model.grid.get_neighbors_within_distance(self, center=False, distance=self.distance)
        if self.condition == "On Fire":
            for n in neighbors:
                if n.condition == "Fine":
                    n.condition = "On Fire"
            self.condition = "Burned Out"

        # option 2 (display but no model step either)
        # other_agents = self.model.schedule.agents
        # if self.condition == "Fine":
        #     for agent in other_agents:
        #         if self.distance < self.model.grid.distance(self, agent):
        #             if agent.condition == "On Fire":
        #                 self.condition = "On Fire"


class Fire(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = GeoSpace()
        self.schedule = RandomActivation(self)
        # agent located from shapefile
        buildings_agent_kwargs = dict(model=self)
        ac = AgentCreator(agent_class=Buildings, agent_kwargs=buildings_agent_kwargs)
        agents = ac.from_GeoDataFrame(gdf_buildings, unique_id="TARGET_FID")
        self.grid.add_agents(agents)
        self.dc = DataCollector({"Fine": lambda m: self.count_type(m, "Fine"),
                                 "On Fire": lambda m: self.count_type(m, "On Fire"),
                                 "Burned Out": lambda m: self.count_type(m, "Burned Out")})
        self.running = True

        # Set up agents
        print("{} agents set up in the Fire model".format(len(agents)))
        for agent in agents:
            agent.condition = "Fine"
            if random.random() < agent.IgnProb_bl:
                agent.condition = "On Fire"
                print("building on fire: {}".format(agent.unique_id))

            self.schedule.add(agent)

    def step(self):
        """
        Advance the model by one step.
        if no building on Fire, stop the model
        """
        # collect data
        self.dc.collect(self)
        # step in time
        print("STEP MODEL")
        self.schedule.step()


        # Halt if no more fire
        if self.count_type(self, "On Fire") == 0:
            self.running = False


    @staticmethod
    def count_type(model, agent_condition):
        '''
        Helper method to count agents in a given condition in a given model.
        '''
        count = 0
        for agent in model.schedule.agents:
            if agent.condition == agent_condition:
                count += 1
        return count


# Run model
fire = Fire()
fire.run_model()

# plot output
results = fire.dc.get_model_vars_dataframe()
results.head()
results.plot()
```

I got this result from the plotting the shape file:

[building shape file with ignition probability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WhPV.png)

But I got this as result:

[empty output with no model step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoSGl.png)

Here are the results I get when I run the model:

```
58 agents set up in the Fire model
building on fire: 30450
building on fire: 30453
building on fire: 30455
building on fire: 30472
building on fire: 30791
building on fire: 30793
STEP MODEL
results
   Fine  On Fire  Burned Out
0    52        6           0
```

I am new to ABM and scratching my head about this one ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `self.model.grid.get_neighbors_within_distance()` returns an empty list and/or no neighbors that can be ignited. Therefore after the first step all the buildings are burned out, your stop condition is met (no buildings on fire) and the model stops running (drive`model.running` is set to False).

This might be related to a wrong "critical distance", a wrong CRS (try setting it explicitly for the grid) or a bug in Mesa geo.

Comment: I tested for the "critical distance" and updated the Geospace with the CRS - no luck. It seems that the neighbors are actually set "on fire" but never recorded as AGENT on fire. So for the same unique_id I have a neighbor "on fire" and agent "fine"